# ActiveRecord does not respect daylight saving time (DST)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, timezone, dst

We're in the timezone `Bern`, which is `+0100`. But since we're now in summertime (we have daylight saving time), the current offset is `+0200`. In my rails app, I set the timezone using a wrapper in the application controller since I need to have user-based timezones:

```
around_filter :user_timezone

def user_timezone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_timezone, &block)
end
```

Now the strange part:

```
Time.zone.now                # 2013-04-10 10:32:56 +0200
                             # (correct offset)

SomeArModel.first.created_at # 2013-03-28 17:49:59 +0100
                             # (incorrect offset, no DST)
```

Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats normal behavior, the DST change happened on `Sun Mar 31 01:00:00 UTC 2013`.

```
t = Time.mktime(2013, 03, 31, 1, 15, 0)

6.times do
  t += 900
  u = Time.at(t.to_i).utc
  puts t.to_s  + " " + u.to_s
end
```

output:

```
Sun Mar 31 01:30:00 +0100 2013 Sun Mar 31 00:30:00 UTC 2013
Sun Mar 31 01:45:00 +0100 2013 Sun Mar 31 00:45:00 UTC 2013
Sun Mar 31 03:00:00 +0200 2013 Sun Mar 31 01:00:00 UTC 2013
Sun Mar 31 03:15:00 +0200 2013 Sun Mar 31 01:15:00 UTC 2013
Sun Mar 31 03:30:00 +0200 2013 Sun Mar 31 01:30:00 UTC 2013
Sun Mar 31 03:45:00 +0200 2013 Sun Mar 31 01:45:00 UTC 2013
```